Angular State of ComponentStore<T>.updater is undefined
I have this ComponentStore
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SceneGraphStore extends ComponentStore<SceneGraphState> {
  private readonly sceneGraphUtils = new SceneGraphUtils();

  public constructor(
    public readonly sceneGraphProxy: SceneGraphProxy,
    public readonly messageService: MessageService,
    private readonly machineDetailStore: MachineDetailsStore,
  ) {
    super({ isLoading: false, sceneGraph: undefined });
  }

  public readonly isLoading$ = this.select((state) => state.isLoading);
  public readonly sceneGraph$ = this.select((state) => state.sceneGraph);
  public readonly equipmentNumber$ = this.machineDetailStore.equipmentNumber$;

  public readonly loadSceneGraph = this.effect(loadSceneGraph(this));

  public readonly updateAxes = this.updater((state, changes: any) => {
    console.log('Current State:', state); // Debugging statement
    if (!state.sceneGraph) {
      console.warn('Scene graph is not initialized');
      return state;
    }

    console.log('Received Changes:', changes); // Debugging statement

    const updatedSceneGraph: ObservableNode = this.sceneGraphUtils.createObservableSceneGraph(state.sceneGraph);
    for (const change of changes) {
      const affectedNode = this.sceneGraphUtils.getNodeByName(updatedSceneGraph, change.name!);
      if (affectedNode) {
        affectedNode.matrix = change.matrix!;
      }
    }

    console.log('Updated scene graph:', updatedSceneGraph); // Debugging statement

    return {
      ...state,
      sceneGraph: updatedSceneGraph as TcNode,
    };
  });

  // Adding a method to initialize the scene graph state
  public readonly initializeSceneGraph = this.updater((state, sceneGraph: TcNode) => ({
    ...state,
    sceneGraph,
  }));

  // Method to get current state for debugging
  public getCurrentState(): SceneGraphState {
    return this.get();
  }
}

The problem is that the state within the update method updateAxes is always undefined.
Even though I load the data correctly and is initialized.
State is always undefined. (changes have data - it comes from the backend).
I have this effect
export const loadSceneGraph = (store: SceneGraphStore) => (equipmentNumber$: Observable<void>) =>
  equipmentNumber$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => store.equipmentNumber$),
    filter((equipmentNumber) => equipmentNumber !== undefined),
    tap(() => store.patchState({ isLoading: true })),
    switchMap((equipmentNumber) =>
      store.sceneGraphProxy.getSceneGraph(equipmentNumber!).pipe(
        tapResponse(
          (sceneGraph) => {
            console.log('SceneGraph loaded:', sceneGraph); // Debugging statement
            store.patchState({ sceneGraph, isLoading: false });
            console.log('State after patching:', store.getCurrentState()); // Debugging statement to check state
          },
          (error: HttpErrorResponse) => store.messageService.showMessageAnalyticsHttpError(error),
        ),
        finalize(() => {
          store.patchState({ isLoading: false });
          console.log('Final state after patching:', store.getCurrentState()); // Final state check
        }),
      ),
    ),
  );

According to the log, the state is initialized.
Effect is used in a component on ngOnInit.
It fetches data from the backend and set the state.
In the component I load the data like this:
public ngOnInit() {
    this.sceneGraphStore.loadSceneGraph();
    this.sceneGraphStore.sceneGraph$.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)).subscribe((sceneGraph) => {
      if (sceneGraph) {
        console.log('Initial SceneGraph loaded in component:', sceneGraph);
        this.sceneGraphService.initializeSceneGraph(sceneGraph);
        this.sceneGraph = this.sceneGraphUtils.createObservableSceneGraph(sceneGraph);
      }
    });

    this.subscribeLiveConnection();
    this.handleLiveData();
  }

Also here log tells me sceneGraph Object is initialized.
But when do any updates, the store is empty, why?
The updateAxes method is triggered when data from the backend is sent.
My guess:
The thing is updateAxes will get triggered when data from backend comes.. the data comes from Redis and is sent continously in short time (live data from machines).
Probably some race condition is the problem?

This may help:
public readonly updateAxes = this.updater((state, changes: any) => {
  if (!state.sceneGraph) {
    console.warn('Scene graph is not initialized');
    return state;
  }

  const updatedSceneGraph = this.sceneGraphUtils.createObservableSceneGraph(state.sceneGraph);
  
  changes.forEach(change => {
    const node = this.sceneGraphUtils.getNodeByName(updatedSceneGraph, change.name);
    if (node) node.matrix = change.matrix;
  });

  return { ...state, sceneGraph: updatedSceneGraph as TcNode };
});

This simplified version:

Checks if sceneGraph exists in the current state
Creates an updated scene graph
Applies changes to the relevant nodes
Returns a new state with the updated scene graph

To use this, call it like:
this.sceneGraphStore.updateAxes(changesFromBackend);

This approach should resolve the issue

It is the same error. state.sceneGraph is undefined. I can't understand why, even though previously it is initialized but somehow in this updater function it is undefined
